# Result from userform comboBox, look up/match then display result from adjacent cell in userform label

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I’m putting together a userform for the first time for a friend who’s starting up a business to create quotes. It's to look up supplier details and material costs from a database and create a quote.

I’m struggling to use the data from the comboBoxes for a look up and then displayed in a label… to later appear on the quote.

I’m using two comboboxes to filter data, base on the user input, I’ve got that working fine.

The bit I can’t get round is taking the result from the second comboBox and showing data from a horizontal adjacent cell in a label.

The code I have that displays nothing in the label is:

```
Private Sub Label14_Click()

    Dim WF As WorksheetFunction
    Dim Bx2 As String
    Bx2 = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    Set WF = WorksheetFunction
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Bx2 = WF.Index(.Columns(2), WF.Match(WF.Max(.Columns(3)), .Columns(3), False))
        Label14.Caption = "Bx2"
    End With

    Label14.Caption = "Bx2"
End Sub
```

I want the result from the userform comboBox, look up/match in an array, and then display the result from the adjacent cell in a userform label.

Update...
Thanks for the feedback why the label caption wasn’t working... absolutely right remove the "" 
I still have an issue... the index and match keeps returning a run time error but I don’t understand why..
The error says Method'Range of object'_worksheet'failed 
The code now looks like this...

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim WF As WorksheetFunction
Dim Bx2 As String, Res
Dim rng As Range, v
Set rng = Sheet3.Range("B2", Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
Set WF = WorksheetFunction
v = rng.Offset(0, 1)
Bx2 = Me.ComboBox2.Value

Res = WF.Index(Sheet3.Range(rng), WF.Match(Bx2, Sheet3.Range(rng), 0), WF.Match(Bx2, Sheet3.Range("v"), 0))


Label14.Caption = Res

End Sub
```

Comment: why using quotes with `Label14.Caption = "Bx2"` ?

Comment: Remove the quotes from `Bx2`

Comment: Thanks Ahmed & Tim.. I removed the "" and the caption started to work.. I have another issue now, a run time error as per the edited question above